# Can template yaml use parameters of parent yaml?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I hope to use the parameters from parent, as below code shown. But when running the pipeline, the result is unexpected.

What can I do to use the parameter from parent?

```
# template.yml
- job: TestJob
  steps:
  - ${{ if parameters.isFromParent }}:  # What can I do to use the parameter from parent?
    - task:
      ....
```

```
# parent.yml
parameters:
- name: isFromParent
  type: Boolean
- template: template.yml
```

Answer (score 5):

You just need to pass it to the inner template. in `template.yml` add:

```
parameters:
- name: isFromParent
  type: Boolean
```

And pass it in the `parent.yml`:

```
- template: template.yml
  parameters:
    isFromParent: ${{ parameters.isFromParent }}
```